# What does "Change" represent in the User Leagues?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

What does the *Change* field represent on the [User Leagues page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) for SO? Refer to the highlighted areas in the image below:

[image: User League Ranking]

- **Rank:** the user's ranking for the selected time period (week, month, quarter, year)
- **Change:** +/- change representing... ???
- **Total Reputation:** the user's total reputation
- **[Time Period] Reputation**: the user's reputation for the selected time period (week, month, quarter, year)

So what is the *Change* field measuring?

Comment: There's definitely potential for confusion here, given the number of questions about this issue (and the mere fact that I too landed here). How about [adding column headers to clarify](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/241908/150034)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The change of rank relative to the previous time interval.

For example, [on the week of 2010 Aug 23rd](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2010-08-23), Pekka's rank was #7, and on the [previous week](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2010-08-16) his rank was #23, so the change is 23 − 7 = +16.

Comment: A feature request should be raised to rename it to `rank changed`. Its really confusing to many like me..