# What does change mean in weekly leagues summary?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-leagues

I see my status below from https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow

[image]

Now I can understand what others terms mean here like `week rank`, `total reputation` and `week reputation`. But what does `change` mean here?

Comment: You were on 3888th position last week. You climbed the leaderboard by 2519 positions.

Comment: Ahh, that actually means `rank changed`. Got it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Change" represent in the User Leagues?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63476/what-does-change-represent-in-the-user-leagues)

Comment: @Kulfy yes it answered my question. However I feel a feature request should be raised to rename it to `rank changed`. Its really confusing to many people like me. Thanks