# What's going on here with the quoted quarter reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

[image]

This user is shown to have a +6268 change in quarter reputation when the user doesn't have that much reputation in the first place. What's going on here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Change" represent in the User Leagues?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63476/what-does-change-represent-in-the-user-leagues)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means they are now ranked 59 and last quarter they were ranked 6268 + 59 = 6327. I.e. that column shows the change in rank, not changes in reputation.